# Automatic start/refresh of ListBox

Tags: c#

I want to make a status listbox, which indicates a Server, basicly saying "server started"
"connecting" etc. but my problem is i dont get the listbox to run. i dont know how to start the loop which is in the ListBox so it shows anything. Do i have to use a trigger to start it?

ive tried Application.run() but that wont work either
and a while(true) loop but nothing here either

```
private void chatverlauf_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chatverlauf.Items.Add(" TEST ");
        }
```

i want it to instantly be active, like in the showcase code i want if the programm is started to show " TEST "

Comment: If you want to update a Listview Items from time to time, you may do it in a timer, ... what does it have to do with SelectedIndexChanged of the listview?

Comment: i dont know what SelectedIndexChanged means, its just there, do i have to do something to it?

So a way to do it is set up a timer in the Form1_Load which does chatverlauf.enter(); ? or how do i do it?

Comment: I added an answer, the code goes to Form_Load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a timer that each time it runs, either update the list view's current items or just clear and re-add new items:

```
Timer timer = new Timer{ Interval = 60000, Enabled = true };  //every minute
timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    chatverlauf.Items.Clear();
    var StatusList = ... // get the list of servers status
    chatverlauf.SuspendLayout();
    foreach(var s in StatusList)
    {
        chatverlauf.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]{s.Name, s.Status});
    }
    chatverlauf.ResumeLayout();
};
```